# Umbraco v5 how to get media file URL in razor view

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco5

I'm new to Umbraco version 5 and [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine), but I'm trying to get the path for a media file stored as a property of the current page so that I can render it as an image.

Searching Google and Stack Overflow have got me this far:

```
@{
    var mediaId = DynamicModel.Animation;
    var media = (TypedEntity)Umbraco.GetEntityById(mediaId);
}
```

where 'Animation' is the name of the media property in my page.

How can I get to the image path of my media item?

Comment: UPDATE: For anyone starting out with Umbraco v5 - be aware that v5 has been discontinued (http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl` helper method. In my case:

```
<img src="@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl(DynamicModel.myImageProperty)" />
```

where `myImageProperty` is the name of the property in my page.

I hope this helps someone.

(OK, I found the answer to my own question, seems I was too lazy to study the sample book store site in detail which explains why there wasn't more information on the web.)

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. I've been battling this for the last two hours.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for a media picker in version 7?                                @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
     Layout = "umbLayout.cshtml";
 }


@Umbraco.RenderMacro("InsertWidgit", new {mediaFile=@CurrentPage.mediaFile})

Answer (score 1):

DynamicModel is deprecated and will be removed in Umbraco 5.3,
instead of it you should use CurrentPage:

`<img src="@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl(CurrentPage.imageProperty)" />`